# No internet connection and timeout in XMLHTTPRequest Script

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have this code on alot of functions for my web app

```
function ui_editlocation(id){

var hr   = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url  = "scripts/ui_processing.php";

var ui   = "editlocation";

var vars = "ui="+ui+"&id="+id;

hr.open("POST", url, true);

hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

hr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {

        var return_data = hr.responseText;

        document.getElementById("ui_content").innerHTML = return_data;

    }

}

hr.send(vars);

document.getElementById("ui_content").innerHTML = "Loading...";

}
```

I want to add some code that if the internet connection is down you get a message saying 'Please check your internet connection, click here to try again'

also if there is an internet connection i want it to timeout after 30 seconds and say 'We are currently experiencing high demand on our network, click here to try again'

I need the 'click here to try again' to re send the request

I know this is a big ask, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Carl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function ui_editlocation(id){
var hr   = new XMLHttpRequest();
var timeout=setTimeout(function(){
    hr.abort();
    timeout=null;
    if(confirm("Do you want to try again?")){ui_editlocation(id);}
},30000);

var url  = "scripts/ui_processing.php";

var ui   = "editlocation";

var vars = "ui="+ui+"&id="+id;

hr.open("POST", url, true);

hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

hr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        if(timeout){cancelTimeout(timeout);timeout=null;}

        var return_data = hr.responseText;

        document.getElementById("ui_content").innerHTML = return_data;

    }

}

hr.send(vars);

document.getElementById("ui_content").innerHTML = "Loading...";

}
```